# How to convert a string to CCSID 37 in java

Tags: java, data-conversion

I want to convert a java string say "HelloWorld" to numerical CCSID 37 numbers. But I can't find any API in java to do this.

[CCSID37](https://www-01.ibm.com/software/globalization/ccsid/ccsid37.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
String.getBytes(System.getProperty("com.ibm.cics.jvmserver.local.ccsid"))
String(bytes, System.getProperty("com.ibm.cics.jvmserver.local.ccsid"))
```

Refer [Data encoding from IBM](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGMCP_5.1.0/com.ibm.cics.ts.java.doc/topics/encoding.html) for details

> The JCICS API uses the code page that is specified in the CICS region
>   and not the underlying JVM. So if the JVM uses a different file
>   encoding, your application must handle different code pages. To help
>   you determine which code page CICS is using, CICS provides several
>   Java properties:
>
> - The com.ibm.cics.jvmserver.supplied.ccsid property returns the code    page that is specified for the CICS region. By default, the JCICS API 
>     uses this code page for its character encoding. However, this value
>     can be overridden in the JVM server configuration.
> - The com.ibm.cics.jvmserver.override.ccsid property returns the value    of an override in the JVM profile. The value is a code page
>     that the    JCICS API uses for its character encoding, instead of the
>     code page    that is used by the CICS region.
> - The com.ibm.cics.jvmserver.local.ccsid property returns the code page    that the JCICS API is using for character encoding in the JVM
>     server.

Comment: which API? i mean jar?its part of jdk?

Comment: @BelieveToLive:- Its the [JCICS API](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGMCP_5.2.0/com.ibm.cics.ts.java.doc/topics/dfhpjla.html). Also see: https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGMCP_5.3.0/com.ibm.cics.ts.java.doc/topics/dfhpjl9.html